# How to override 'UIScrollView.delegate'?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

When I look at `UITableView`, I find that `UITableView` 's `UITableViewDelegate` inherit from `UIScrollViewDelegate` in order to override `UIScrollView`'s `delegate`

Here is how i implement my own subclass of 'UIScrollView'.

```
protocol UIFormViewDelegate:NSObjectProtocol, UIScrollViewDelegate{
}
class UIFormView: UIScrollView {
    override var delegate:UIFormViewDelegate?
}
```

The problem is that the compiler gives a warning:

> Property 'delegate' with type 'UIFormViewDelegate?' cannot override a property with type 'UIScrollViewDelegate?'

Can anybody tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the type of `delegate`

What you can do is something like that

```
class DelegateClass: NSObject, UIFormViewDelegate {

}

class UIFormView: UIScrollView {
    func setUpDelegate() {
        self.delegate = DelegateClass()
    }
}
```

And then call the `setUpDelegate` from somewhere where it makes sense

Comment: if so, why UITableView override delegate successfully

Comment: Because that code written in Objective-C. If you implement `UIFormView` class in Obj-C you also will be able to do that, but not using Swift